# Bokeh: Whats the differences between certain methods of editing data in a ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a question regarding the `ColumnDataSource` in a Bokeh 2.3.0 Server application.
Below is an example that tries to illustrate my question. Eventough it is a littlebit longer, I've spend a lot of effort making it as minimal but complete as possible.

So, there are at least two major ways of editing the data in `ColumnDataSource` that I know will work.
**First one** is by using the 'index_way' (I don't know how to call this method correctly) by using `source.data['my_column_name'][<numpy_like_array_indexing>] = 'my_new_value'` where `<numpy_like_array_indexing>` can result in something like `[0:10]` or `[[True,False,True]]`, ect. to subset the data like a numpy array. This way, one can use the `source.selected.indices` to index the data for example.

The **second** method is using the [`.patch()` function](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.patch) of `ColumnDataSource`. Which the reference calls describes as *Efficiently update data source columns at specific locations*.

The **third** method I came accross in my code is when editing/changing a complete column in `ColumnDataSource` like `source.data['my_data_column_1'] = source.data['my_data_column_2']`. This way, I can set a data column to an already existing one.

**My question is:** Are they designed to behave differently? I found that changes using the 'index' method are not propagated or updated to the HoverTool, wheares for the other two methods, this seem to work.
This behavior can be seen in the following code example. When changing the first few samples in the plot, by selecting them with the selection tool and editing `source.data['Label']` via `label_selected_via_index()` the HoverTool does not show the correct and updated value of 'Label'. However, the change in the data was acutally performed, which can be seen by `check_label()` which accesses and prints the first few samples of `source.data['Label']`.
Changing the `Label` Value with one of the other methods does indeed show the correct and updated value when hovering over the data.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper, Dropdown, Button, HoverTool
from bokeh.layouts import layout
import random
import time

plot_data = 'Value1'
LEN = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[i for i in range(LEN)], 
                   "Value1":[random.random() for i in range(LEN)], 
                   "Value2":[random.random() for i in range(LEN)], 
                   "Color": [int(random.random()*10) for i in range(LEN)] })

df['plot_data'] = df[plot_data]
df['Label'] = "No Label Set"
df['Label_new_col'] = "Label was added"

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette="Turbo256", low = 0, high = 3)

def make_tooltips():
    return [('ID', '@ID'), 
            ('Label', '@Label'), 
            (plot_data, f'@{plot_data}')]

tooltips = make_tooltips()

hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
plot1 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, tooltips=tooltips, tools='box_select')
plot1.add_tools(hover_tool)                  
circle = plot1.circle(x='ID', y='plot_data', source=source, 
                      fill_color={"field":'Color', "transform":cmap}, 
                      line_color={"field":'Color', "transform":cmap})

def update_plot_data(event):
    global plot_data
    plot_data = event.item
    source.data['plot_data'] = source.data[plot_data]
    hover_tool.tooltips = make_tooltips()

dropdown = Dropdown(label='Change Value', menu=["Value1","Value2"])
dropdown.on_click(update_plot_data)

def label_selected_via_index(event):
    t0 = time.time()
    selected = source.selected.indices
    source.data['Label'][0:10] = 'Label was added'
    hover_tool.tooltips = make_tooltips()
    source.selected.indices = []
    print(f"Time needed for label_selected_via_index: {time.time()-t0:.5f}")

button_set_label1 = Button(label='Set Label via Index')
button_set_label1.on_click(label_selected_via_index)

def label_selected_via_patch(event):
    t0 = time.time()
    selected = source.selected.indices
    patches = [(ind, 'Label was added') for ind in selected]
    source.patch({'Label': patches})
    hover_tool.tooltips = make_tooltips()
    source.selected.indices = []
    print(f"Time needed for label_selected_via_patch: {time.time()-t0:.5f}")

button_set_label2 = Button(label='Set Label via Patch')
button_set_label2.on_click(label_selected_via_patch)

def label_selected_via_new_col(event):
    t0 = time.time()
    selected = source.selected.indices
    source.data['Label'] = source.data['Label_new_col']
    hover_tool.tooltips = make_tooltips()
    source.selected.indices = []
    print(f"Time needed for label_selected_via_new_col: {time.time()-t0:.5f}")

button_set_label3 = Button(label='Set Label via New Column ')
button_set_label3.on_click(label_selected_via_new_col)

def check_label(event):
    print(f"first 10 labels: {[l for l in source.data['Label'][0:10]]}")

button_label_check = Button(label='Check Label')
button_label_check.on_click(check_label)

layout_ = layout([[plot1],
                  [dropdown],
                  [button_set_label1 ,button_set_label2, button_set_label3],
                  [button_label_check]])
curdoc().add_root(layout_)
```

In my application, I have a lot of data and observed, that using `.patch()` does take significantly longer than the indexing version or the replacement of a complete column. In my application, the indexing method needs less than a millisecond, while the patch method needs more than one seconds, which makes everything a little bit more laggy when interactively changing values. Basically, my application is somehow similar to the above example regarding the process of selecting samples in one plot and assigning a label via multiple buttons. Those labels are also shown in muliple plots via the tooltip, so this update is necessary for me.

Is there a way to A) Make the indexing version also updating the Hovertool? I prefer this method, because it is visually much faster or B) Make the `.patch()` version somehow faster?

I hope I could make my problem somehow understandable and be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Is the server you are running remote? When I run your code the `patch` versions take single-digit milliseconds running locally `Time needed for label_selected_via_patch: 0.00463`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a Bokeh server app, it's worth keeping in mind, "what all actually needs to happen for a change to show up in the browser?" And the answer to that is roughly:

- a change is detected (or signaled) in Python
- a change event is serialized and sent over the network to a browser
- the change event is deserialized by BokehJS
- the change is applied and view in the browser is updates

Pretty much Bokeh always handles the last three steps (modulo any actual bugs or TBD features). So the question really boils down to "what are the ways to signal a change" to Bokeh?
Let's start from a position of describing what is available and intended (rather than starting from differences or what is not intended).

#### Direct Assignment to Properties

The number one, primary way to update a Bokeh object in order see a change in the browser is to *assign an entire new value* to a Bokeh property. If you do that, e.g. `.prop_name = new_value`, literally including a "dot" and "equal sign", then Bokeh can auto-magically detect the change and send it to the browser. Here are a few examples:

```py
plot.title.text = "New title"  # updates the title
glyph.line_color = "red"       # change a glyph's line color
slider.value = 10              # sets a slider's value
```

The examples above all show basic scalar (string, number) values, but this works just as well for more complicated values. Another extremely common example of this general mechanism is updating the entire `.data` dict of a `ColumnDataSource`

```py
source.data = {'x': [...], 'y': [...]} # new data for a glyph or table
```

That updates *all* the data in a CDS, so that e.g. a line glyph might re-draw itself.

Depending what you are doing, the size of your data, etc., updating the entire `.data` dict may be expensive (due to serialization, de-serialization, network transit, etc). So there are some other ways that may be more efficient in specific cases.

#### "In-place" Special Cases

The distinguishing characteristic above is that everything is a "whole" assignment, i.e. there are not mutating or in-place modifications. In a few cases, Bokeh can auto-magically handle in-place updates to mutable values. Without getting too into the weeds, by far the most important example of this is setting a *single* new column in a `ColumnDataSource` by using standard Python dict indexing assignment on `.data`:

```py
source.data['x'] = [...]  # Bokeh will automatically handle this
```

This is your **Third** method above. It works fine, but *only* for updating columns in a CDS `.data` dict. This method only sends the one new column of data over the wire. As long as you only need to update one or a few columns in a large CDS, it is probably faster than assigning a new whole `.data` value.

---

What does ***NOT work*** is basically any other kind of mutating, in-place assignment:

```py
source.data['x'][100:200] = [...] # Bokeh does not automatically handle this
```

This is your **First** ("index") method above, and it is a non-starter. This kind of usage will not trigger any changes in the browsers.

The TLDR is that wrapping every CDS sequence in some custom class that overrides the standard getitem/setitem machinery just makes common usage too inefficient, and the trade-off cannot be justified. Bokeh will not auto-magically notice or do anything with with mutating assignments like this. (If you are *purely* in BokehJS JavaScript-side, then you can make in-place assignments like this and then manually call a `change.emit()` to manually trigger updates, but that is *only* for the pure JS side of things).

#### Dedicated APIs for Optimized Cases

Recognizing that sometimes even restricting CDS updates to a single column is still not efficient enough, the [`patch`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html?highlight=patch#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource.patch) and [`stream`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html?highlight=patch#bokeh.models.sources.AjaxDataSource.stream) methods were added to `ColumnDataSource`.

These methods are for cases like:

- I want to append  few new values to the end of all my columns, instead of sending all the data again. (e.g for streaming new stock ticker or other sensor data efficiently)
- I want to update a few specific values in the middle of my large time series or image, but only send the updated values and not re-send everything else.

This is your **Second** method and is typically much faster for small updates relative to total data size. As for `patch` specifically, you can see e.g. the [`patch_app.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.4/examples/howto/patch_app.py) example in the [examples folder](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/branch-2.4/examples):

[image]

This example updates a three separate scatter, multi-line, and image plots all simultaneously at a 20Hz update rate. The checked-in version has fairly modest data sizes, but I tested it again locally by bumping all the data to 10–100x larger, and it still kept up. If you are seeing something different from patch (i.e. multi-second update times), then a complete [Minimal Reproducing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed to actually investigate.

Comment: Thanks for this very long, detailed and valuable answer with all those in-depth information! I Really appreciate it. It makes a lot more clear, how Bokeh works "under the hood" and what to use and what not to use.

Comment: I investigated further into the speed of updating a column in a CDS. I thought, that updating one column via `source.data['x'] = [...]` is uneffected of how many other columns there are within the CDS and only depends on the number of rows within the CDS. (Since I´m only updating one specific column) However, I did a quick analysis and observed, that the time it takes to update one column (with a fixed number of samples in it) increases lineraly with the number of total columns of the CDS. So my problem is, that I have roughly 200 columns (5000 rows) in my CDS which just seems to be too much..

Comment: That seems unexpected to me but it would require a complete [Minimal Reproducing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to actually run and investigate to speculate more.

Comment: And if you can supply an MRE that demonstrates this, the appropriate place to report it is in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)

Comment: I started a [Discussion on the Bokeh forum](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/why-does-the-speed-of-updating-one-column-in-a-cds-increases-with-the-number-of-total-columns/7529) with a MRE.